# What is the pattern for Instagram photo URLs?

Tags: string, url, random, instagram, reverse-engineering

When uploading a photo to Instagram, a unique URL is generated (e.g. `https://instagram.com/p/0_Cy2pkW0k/` or `https://instagram.com/p/zIhovthQQP/`). I've noticed that

1. the strings at the end of the URL are more or less sequential (though they seem to loop back every few months),
2. not every string has a photo associated to it (e.g. `https://instagram.com/p/zIhovthQQO/` and `https://instagram.com/p/zIhovthQQQ/` link to nothing)
3. and the strings consist of upper- and lower-case letters, numbers and the underscore character.

If I knew the timestamp of a photo and its uploader, would it be possible for me to know the URL string as well? Ideally, my goal would be to know that if I uploaded a photo at a certain time, I could know in advance what its URL would be.

More generally, if I had a large database of strings, how would I go about in trying to reverse engineer the way the strings are generated?

Comment: Are you asking specifically about Instagram here? or you are asking in general?

Comment: @Alundra I want to solve the problem for Instagram specifically, although any kind of help about how to do this in general would be appreciated.